# c# RESTSHARP Deserialize json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, restsharp

How can i perform Deserialize on below json format with two dimension? i have look for many solutions and try applied but failed. Below are my code, can tell me which part is wrong ??

Im using rest api to request client, and the response data is in json format, i wanna break down further to get the age,gender,identity details and so on. how can i perform it? thanks in advance

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/detect_faces?api_key=dcd38b28dee23fe70a261421785a0ff6983dfe08&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpbs.twimg.com%2Fprofile_images%2F526212687101820929%2FwmAKmxjb.jpeg&version=2017-11-06 ");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.AddParameter("application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response.Content);

            Debug.WriteLine("age===");
            Debug.WriteLine("ageMax===");
            Debug.WriteLine("ageMin===");
            Debug.WriteLine("ageScore===");
        }
    }
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Result[] images { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public faces[] faces { get; set; }
    }

    public class faces
    {

        public string age { get; set; }
        public string max { get; set; }
        public string min { get; set; }
        public string score { get; set; }
    }
```

### JSON FORMAT

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "faces": [
                {
                    "age": {
                        "max": 64,
                        "min": 55,
                        "score": 0.408852
                    },
                    "face_location": {
                        "height": 759,
                        "left": 243,
                        "top": 151,
                        "width": 597
                    },
                    "gender": {
                        "gender": "MALE",
                        "score": 0.99593
                    },
                    "identity": {
                        "name": "Najib Razak",
                        "score": 0.99593
                    }
                }
            ],
            "resolved_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/526212687101820929/wmAKmxjb.jpeg",
            "source_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/526212687101820929/wmAKmxjb.jpeg"
        }
    ],
    "images_processed": 1
}
```

Comment: You have the properties of the `faces` object as `string`, but they are clearly supposed to be objects with properties themselves. How about you search for a JSON to C# converter and compare the C# it gives with what you have?

Comment: Thanks! just found the converter from json to c# .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this class model:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("images")]
    public Image[] Images { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("images_processed")]
    public long ImagesProcessed { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    [JsonProperty("faces")]
    public Face[] Faces { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("resolved_url")]
    public string ResolvedUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source_url")]
    public string SourceUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Face
{
    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public Age Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("face_location")]
    public FaceLocation FaceLocation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("identity")]
    public Identity Identity { get; set; }
}

public class Identity
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public double Score { get; set; }
}

public class Gender
{
    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string PurpleGender { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public double Score { get; set; }
}

public class FaceLocation
{
    [JsonProperty("height")]
    public long Height { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("left")]
    public long Left { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("top")]
    public long Top { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("width")]
    public long Width { get; set; }
}

public class Age
{
    [JsonProperty("max")]
    public long Max { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("min")]
    public long Min { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class structure is wrong

The faces class should contain other class properties

```
public class Faces
{
    public Age age {get;set;}
    public FaceLocation face_location {get;set;}
    public Gender gender {get;set;}
    public Identity identity {get;set;}
}
public class Age 
{
    public int max {get;set;}
    public int min {get;set;}
    public double score {get;set;}
}
```

And so on for other class properties in Faces

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create your custom ***"JsonConverter"***

Here is an example : 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

You'll have full control on the process to deserialize your json into the POCO that you want.